# Как убрать автоматический скрол вверх

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть скрипт , который используется для обновления div , но при обновлении div скролл уходит вверх, если скрол находится по середине то при обновлении уходит вверх.

Как можно это исправить?

Сам скрипт:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
          $("#result").load(window.location.href + " #result" );
    }, 3000);
    });
    </script>
    
    <div id="result">content</div>
```

Comment: Потестировал в хроме. Все работает. Скролл не дергается, остается на месте

Comment: вы внутри div проверили? при обновлении в диве он дергается..

Comment: Запоминать позицию скрола "до" преобразования `y = el.scrollY, x = el.scrollX`. После преобразования проверять. Если он не такой - устанавливать в нужное место `el.scrollTo(x, y)`. Где `el` ссылка на сам элемент.

Comment: Зачем ты дописываешь `#result` у текущему УРЛ? Это означает загрузить страницу с УРЛ и проскролить до такого якоря или элемента с таким ИД.